# How to bind to different implementation in each request in a web app using guice

Tags: java, guice

I have setup a Filter for a specific set of requests i.e. */dispatch through my Guice Listener.

In this filter I want to change the binding for type  BaseService (an interface containing one method )  in each request based on the Request URI. i.e. if the URI is /hello/dispatch I want BaseService to bind to HelloServiceImpl else if the URI is /bye/dispatch I want to bind to ByeServiceImpl . Both implement the BaseService .

Now somewhere in one my random class that participates in the servlet request handling I want to inject the appropriate implementation of BaseService specific to current request.

Is this possible ? How ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a factory pattern for providing different types of BaseService.

```
public interface ServiceFactory
{
  public BaseService create(String uri);
}

public class ServiceFactoryImpl implements ServiceFactory
{
  @Override
  public BaseService create(String uri)
  {
    if(uri.equals("/hello/dispatch"))
      return new HelloServiceImpl();

    else if (uri.equals("/bye/dispatch"))
      return new ByeServiceImpl();

    return null;
  }
}
```

Then the factory in your module.

```
bind(ServiceFactory.class).to(ServiceFactoryImpl.class);
```

and inject this into the Request.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you'll want `uri.equals("/hello/dispatch")` instead of `==`. Also, if HelloServiceImpl and GoodbyeServiceImpl need dependencies themselves, you can create a constructor using `@Inject` that takes `Provider<HelloService>` and `Provider<ByeService>` to let Guice create and inject the services for you.

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by "inject this into the request" ?